# Implement auto fill otp code functionality in cordova and ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am currently working in ionic and cordova.I am implementing OTP in my app.I just want to know how can i detect that OTP has been received and implement auto fill OTP code functionality.Is there any built in plug in for this functionality???
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is the OTP received by SMS?

Comment: yes it is recieved by sms.

Comment: Did you find any solution on this?

Comment: Not yet.Implemented in native android.

Comment: hello did you find any solution for this.

Comment: @Keshav sir do you get some  any solution for this ?

Comment: No guys, I have not found any solution yet.

Comment: I have implemented a method to do in native android code for cordova app.